# Add a class if var < 0 jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, addclass

I do not know what I am doing wrong. For some reason I can not add this class to the #total-weight with JS. The CSS is fine because I have hard coded and is working. The sum is working perfect as well.

/********** This is my HTML **************/

```
<tr id="results">
    <td>Grade (%)</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="" id="final-grade" name="final-grade"></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="100" id="total-weight" name="total-weight"><span><small> remaining (%)</small></span></td>
</tr>
```

/******** This is my JS ***************/

```
'use strict';
$(document).on('keyup', '.weight-value', function() {

    // the sum of weight (%)
    var sumWeight = 0;
    var totalWeight = 0;
    $('.weight-value').each(function(){
        sumWeight += +$(this).val();
    });// end of sum of weight (%)

    // populate weigth remaining
    totalWeight = $('#total-weight').val(100 - sumWeight);

        if(totalWeight < 0) {
            $('#total-weight').addClass('table-border');
        }

});// end document .on keyup
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('#total-weight').val(100 - sumWeight)` will set the value of the element and return a jQuery object. So your condition will not work.

Also you might want to use `toggleClass()`, since you want to remove the class if the value is >=0

```
'use strict';
$(document).on('keyup', '.weight-value', function () {

    // the sum of weight (%)
    var sumWeight = 0;
    var totalWeight = 0;
    $('.weight-value').each(function () {
        sumWeight += +$(this).val();
    }); // end of sum of weight (%)

    // populate weigth remaining
    totalWeight = 100 - sumWeight;
    $('#total-weight').val(totalWeight);

    $('#total-weight').toggleClass('table-border', totalWeight < 0);

}); // end document .on keyup
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jnznzk9p/)

Comment: Do you know any website that I can go and practice javascript or jquery or any of the js framework?

Comment: @gilbert there are a lot of tutorial sites... like Codecademy... I haven't used them also resources like http://jqfundamentals.com/ or http://learn.jquery.com/